# CSS Line-Height Guide

Tags: css

I remember reading a style guide explaining what the proper line-height should be for each element. I can't find it on google.

I would appreciate it if anyone could link me to such a guide, or perhaps explain it in an answer.

Thanks!

Edit: SORRY, please let me clarify. I'm not asking about how to use CSS to set line-heights, but what the recommended line-heights are for various elements. eg headers, paragraph text, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe these references are more like what you're looking for.  I haven't found a definitive rule, but at least here are some things to consider.

This one suggests that it depends on your choice of font-family:
http://www.webteacher.ws/2009/09/30/improve-readability-with-line-height/

This one suggests that it depends on the width of the lines:
http://kingdesk.com/articles/optimal-line-height/

This reference essentially agrees with both of those:
http://www.wpdesigner.com/2007/06/21/web-typography-line-spacing/

The main rules seem to be (1) wider lines of text require greater line-heights, and (2) greater line-height is required based on font if the height of lower-case letters is a high percentage of the height of upper-case letters.

The best approach is probably just to eyeball it, and try to avoid impenetrable walls of text.

Comment: @Alon I updated the broken link to point to an archived copy.  Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 8):

The info [here](http://usabletype.com/css/text/line-height/) is pretty basic, but useful.

To summarize:

The default `line-height:normal` gives `line-height:1.2`, 120% of the font size.  If you're going to change it, it's still usually best to use a number with no units, e.g., `lineheight:1.5` (150% the font size), because then the line-height for an element will be computed from *that element's* font size, even if the line height was inherited from an element with different font size.

If you instead say `line-height:10em`, it's computed from the font on the element where the line-height was specified . . . that may be wrong if this line-height is inherited by an element with a different font size.

Likewise a specific number of pixels such as `line-height:10px` could certainly be wrong if it's inherited by elements with different font size.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually 120% (of the font size).

Answer (score 0):

W3 schools recommends ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_line-height)) a line height of 1.6, though I've seen that between 1.2 and 1.45 is good as well

Answer (score 0):

Normal line-height value is normal. You can edit that with numbers like 1.6 2 etc

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please provide code with your answer.